# writing text after calling seek() method on StringIO()

Tags: python-3.x

```
from io import StringIO
def pratcise():
    intro = StringIO()
    x = "I study in class 10 and I love Python\n"
    intro.write(x)
    intro.seek(0)

    y = "My name is Prem Singh\n"
    intro.write(y)
    print(intro.getvalue())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pratcise()
```

I have StringIO object, I write some data in it and then i need to write some other data at the start of it but when i change the position through seek and write the other data, the first data has lost.

- Output = "My name is Prem Singh\nnd I love Python"
- Expected = "My name is Prem Singh I study in class 10 and I love Python"

Comment: You told it to go back to the beginning of the file and start again.  Why do you expect the previous contents to survive?  That wouldn't happen with a disk file.  This is behaving exactly as it is supposed to.

Comment: I just need to add some other data at start of the file without loosing, Is it possible or not

Comment: Not with file operations.  That's not how files work.   There's no "insertion".  You can certainly extract the value of the StringIO object as a string, and do whatever you need to do with normal string operations.

Comment: The output of your code is actually `"My name is Prem Singh\nd I love Python"` rather than `"My name is Prem Singh"` due to partial overwrite of only the portion of the previous content up to the length of the new content.

Comment: Thanks all for comments as it help me and The output is wrong as pointed out by @blhsing, I am going to correct it

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a few ways of achieving this, but as one of the comments has correctly pointed out, it will not be effificent (for big data) because the code would be pushing all the data down a line (this is how files work).

Here is one (of a few examples):

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()

lines.insert(0, 'new line\n') 

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.writelines(lines)
```

this will work fine for small files...